# Smallest enclosing circle for a convex polygon

Tags: circles, computational-geometry, convex-geometry

The smallest enclosing circle of a set of 2D points is known to be computable in linear time by the Megiddo or Welzl methods. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem). But the first is not practical and the second is randomized.

Is there an ad-hoc solution that meets the $O(N)$ bound when the points are the vertices of a convex polygon ? (Note that as the convex hull of a simple polygon is found in linear time by Melkman's algorithm, the *convex* requirement can be replaced by *simple*.)

Comment: Good question, but isn’t it better suited for the computer science stackexchange?

Comment: @Milten: Mathematics has the computational-geometry tag, and CG problems are not infrequent.

Comment: Fair enough then.

Comment: What would happen if you ran a non-randomized version of Welzl's algorithm on a convex polygon?

Comment: @Théophile: interesting question. I don't know but I assume that if that lead to a linear-time solution for a convex polygon (or convex hull), that result would be well-known.

Comment: Since finding the convex hull is straightforward, if having the convex hull were to lead to a straightforward (practical, non-randomized) linear-time solution, wouldn't the canonical solution for an arbitrary set of points start by finding the convex hull?

Comment: @mjqxxxx: in practice, yes. In theory, that would not improve the worst-case complexity.

Answer (score 3):

As a naive idea we begin with an assertion. Given a convex polygon, the two most distant vertices are contained in the smallest enclosing circle. With this idea we follow considering all the triangles that can be formed using the two more distant vertices and other point pertaining to the polygon. The smallest circle should contain all the triangles. Also we should consider the anomalous "triangle" formed by the two vertices most distant. Follows a MATHEMATICA script which computes the best circle. At the beginning  in `data` there are a sequence of cases which can be tested.

```
data = {{1.7`, 0.27`}, {2.84`, 0.75`}, {3.96`, 0.51`}, {4.93`, -0.61`}, {3.62`, -0.87`}, {2.17`, -0.76`}};
data = {{3.33`, 0.54`}, {3.82`, 0.81`}, {5.06`, 0.83`}, {5.61`, 0.26`}, {5.67`, -0.66`}, {4.82`, -0.76`}, {3.17`, -0.23`}};
data = {{2.41`, 0.34`}, {2.75`, 0.76`}, {3.53`, 0.96`}, {4.61`, 0.84`}, {5.69`, 0.42`}, {5.94`, -0.7`}, {3.39`, -0.87`}, {2.63`, -0.36`}};
data = {{2.65`, 0.87`}, {4.24`, 1.39`}, {5.82`, -0.1`}, {5.22`, -1.92`}, {3.07`, -1.89`}, {2.23`,-0.52`}};
data = {{2.63`, 1.11`}, {3.37`, 1.44`}, {4.8`, 1.29`}, {5.9`, -1.45`}, {4.35`, -2.07`}, {3.04`, -2.12`}, {2.32`, -1.31`}, {2.01`, 0.`}, {2.18`, 0.61`}};
data = {{5.23`, 1.2`}, {4.36`, 1.59`}, {3.34`, 1.51`}, {2.51`,  0.93`}, {2.12`, -0.82`}, {2.54`, -1.69`}, {3.34`, -2.3`}, {4.53`,-2.2`}, {5.73`, -1.47`}, {5.89`, -0.32`}, {5.62`, 0.65`}};
data = {{3.38`, -2.37`}, {2.71`, -2.02`}, {2.27`, -1.21`}, {2.25`, -0.36`}, {2.43`, 0.27`}, {2.87`, 0.91`}, {3.47`, 1.14`}, {4.1`, 1.22`}, {4.75`, 1.18`}, {5.26`, 0.87`}, {5.76`, 0.4`}, {6.01`, -0.65`}, {5.91`, -1.15`}, {5.63`, -1.68`}, {4.91`, -2.15`}, {4.07`, -2.48`}};
error = 0.00001;

verify[data_List, solution_] := Module[{internal = True, i}, 
   For[i = 1, i <= Length[data], i++, 
      If[Norm[data[[i]] - solution[[1]]] - solution[[2]] > error, internal = False]
      ]; 
 Return[internal]
 ]

 cr[tri_List] := Module[{x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3, x0, y0, r},
    {x1, y1} = tri[[1]]; {x2, y2} = tri[[2]]; 
    {x3, y3} = tri[[3]]; 
    r = Sqrt[(x1 - x0)^2 + (y1 - y0)^2]; 
    Return[{{x0, y0}, r} /. Solve[{x1^2 - x2^2 + y1^2 - y2^2 - 2 x0 (x1 - x2) - 2 y0 (y1 - y2) == 0,
                                   x3^2 - x2^2 + y3^2 - y2^2 - 2 x0 (x3 - x2) - 2 y0 (y3 - y2) == 0}, {x0, y0}][[1]]]
  ]

n = Length[data];
dmax = 0;
For[i = 1, i <=  n, i++, 
  For[j = 1, j < i, j++, d = Norm[data[[i]] - data[[j]]]; 
    If[d > dmax, dmax = d; i0 = i; j0 = j]]]
    v = data[[i0]] - data[[j0]];
    p0 = (data[[i0]] + data[[j0]])/2;
    r = Norm[v]/2;
tri = {};
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
  If[(i != i0) && (i != j0), 
    AppendTo[tri, {data[[i0]], data[[i]], data[[j0]]}]]];
circs = Table[cr[tri[[k]]], {k, 1, Length[tri]}]
nc = Length[circs]
If[verify[data, {p0, r}], feasible = {{p0, r}}, feasible = {}]
For[i = 1, i <= nc, i++,
  choosed = verify[data, circs[[i]]];
  If[choosed,
    AppendTo[feasible, circs[[i]]]
  ]
]
rmin = 1000;
For[i = 1, i <= Length[feasible], i++, 
   If[feasible[[i, 2]] < rmin, rmin = feasible[[i, 2]]; ibest = i]]
best = feasible[[ibest]]


xmin = Min[Transpose[data][[1]]] - 1;
xmax = Max[Transpose[data][[1]]] + 1;
ymin = Min[Transpose[data][[2]]] - 1;
ymax = Max[Transpose[data][[2]]] + 1;
aspectratio = (ymax - ymin)/(xmax - xmin);
pc = best[[1]]
r = best[[2]]
gr0 = ListLinePlot[Join[data, {data[[1]]}], PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}];
gr1 = ParametricPlot[u data[[i0]] + (1 - u) data[[j0]], {u, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red];
gr3 = Graphics[Circle[pc, r]];
gr4 = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[pc]}];
gr5 = Table[ListLinePlot[tri[[k]]], {k, 1, Length[tri]}];
Show[gr0, gr1, gr3, gr4, gr5, AspectRatio -> aspectratio,PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Follows a python version to the essential procedures excluding plotting

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA

data =[[3.38, -2.37],
   [2.71, -2.02],
   [2.27, -1.21],
   [2.25, -0.36],
   [2.43, 0.27],
   [2.87, 0.91],
   [3.47, 1.14],
   [4.1, 1.22],
   [4.75, 1.18],
   [5.26,0.87],
   [5.76, 0.4],
   [6.01, -0.65],
   [5.91, -1.15],
   [5.63, -1.68],
   [4.91, -2.15],
   [4.07, -2.48]]

data = [[3.33, 0.54],
    [3.82, 0.81],
    [5.06, 0.83],
    [5.61, 0.26],
    [5.67, -0.66],
    [4.82, -0.76],
    [3.17, -0.23]]

def sub(p1,p2):
    return list(map(lambda i, j: i-j,p1,p2))
def add(p1,p2):
    return list(map(lambda i, j: i+j,p1,p2))
def max_secant(data):
    n = len(data)
    dmax = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            d = LA.norm(sub(data[i],data[j]))
            if d > dmax:
                dmax = d
                i0 = i
                j0 = j                   
    return (i0, j0)

def verify(data, feasible):
    internal = True
    error = 0.00001
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if LA.norm(sub(data[i],feasible[0]))-feasible[1] > error:
            internal = False
    return internal

def polar_form(triangle):
    (x1,y1) = triangle[0]
    (x2,y2) = triangle[1]
    (x3,y3) = triangle[2]
    M = np.array([[2*(x2-x1),2*(y2-y1)],[2*(x2-x3),2*(y2-y3)]]) 
    b = np.array([-(x1**2-x2**2+y1**2-y2**2),-(x3**2 x2**2+y3**2-y2**2)])
    (x0, y0) = list(np.linalg.solve(M,b))
    r = LA.norm([x1-x0,y1-y0])
    return [[x0,y0], r]

def collect_triangles(data, i0, j0):
    triangs = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if i not in [i0, j0]:
            triangs.append([data[i0],data[i],data[j0]])
    return triangs

(i0, j0) = max_secant(data)
v = sub(data[i0],data[j0])
r = 0.5*LA.norm(v)
p1 = add(data[i0],data[j0])
p0 = [element*0.5 for element in p1]
triangles = collect_triangles(data,i0,j0)

polar = []
polar.append([p0,r])

for i in range(len(triangles)):
    polar.append(polar_form(triangles[i]))

feasible = []
for i in range(len(polar)):
    if verify(data,polar[i]):
        feasible.append(polar[i])
    
print("*** best circle ***")
    
bestr = 10000
for i in range(len(feasible)):
    [pc, r] = feasible[i]
    if r < bestr:
        bestr = r
        bestcirc = feasible[i]
    
print(bestcirc)
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not after some code to solve the problem. I am asking if an O(N) solution exists.

Comment: This conclusion can be obtained after the code. Finding the base segment, the sequence of triangles and choosing the best. All this seems $O(N)$

Comment: How do you find the two most distant vertices ? I see a double loop, which does not smell $O(N)$.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I will think if it is possible to reduce that.

Comment: @Yves: Here it is claimed that the diameter of a convex polygon can be computed in O(n): https://stackoverflow.com/a/321994/1187415

Comment: @MartinR: I am referring to the code in this post, which we are deemed to reverse engineer.