# On computing the convex hull

Tags: geometry, algorithms, convex-hulls

I'm given $n$ points $(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n)$, lying on the boundary of a polygon and constituting this polygon (not necessarily convex), whereby those points are given me in clockwise order and I  want to compute the convex hull of this polygon, i.e. determine the set of points $S \subseteq \{p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n\}$ s.t. the points in $S$ shape the convex hull of the polygon. The tricky part is that my runtime constraint is $O(n)$, which is why I'm very stuck on this task. One should output the points of the convex hull in counterclockwise order.

Comment: What do you mean by "compute the convex hull"? In what form do you want the output of your algorithm?

Comment: Google it. You'll quickly find an answer.

Comment: @uniquesolution unfortunately not, the runtime constraint makes it more difficult

Comment: @Klaus I want the subset of the given points that shape the convex hull in form of a list, printed or whatever you prefer (that's not of much importance, rather how the algorithm works)

Comment: @TaChu I recommend adding this to the question as it is very relevant. Other possibilities would be, for instance, "check if a given point $q$ is in the convex hull" or simply " draw the convex hull" and the answer could depend on this.

Comment: It is claimed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4010764/42969) that the convex hull of a simple polygon is found in linear time by Melkman's algorithm.

Comment: @MartinR so am I dealing with a simple polygon in my case? Because I didn't read that off the task. I forgot to mention that it's not said to be convex

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_of_a_simple_polygon

Comment: @Ihf why do I know that it must be a simple polygon?

Comment: @TaChu, "boundary of a polygon" seems to imply it's a simple polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Given an unordered set of points, [Graham scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) yields their convex hull in *O*(*N* log *N*) time complexity.  The limiting factor is the sort phase; everything else is linear in time, as the Wikipedia article explains.

When *N* is a positive integer with a known maximum (for example, 2<sup>32</sup>-1 when using C `uint32_t`, or 2<sup>64</sup>-1 when using C `uint64_t` type), you can use [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) to do the sort phase in linear time, yielding an implementation of Graham scan with linear time complexity, but with a fixed upper limit for *N*.

If the points are given in a suitable order, other algorithms can be used to achieve linear time complexity.

Quite a few algorithms assume the points given are the vertices of a polygon in order – meaning that each consecutive pair of points given are connected with an edge in the polygon, with the initial and final points also connected with an edge.

[Melkman's Convex Hull Algorithm](https://doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(87)90086-X) is probably the best known of these; the Wikipedia [Convex hull of a simple polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_of_a_simple_polygon) article lists a couple more.  These assume that the polygon given is [simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_of_a_simple_polygon) (does not intersect itself, and has no holes); some also assume the polygon is not degenerate (a line segment) or that consecutive points (polygon vertices) are not collinear.

I would recommend you examine your data properties, to see how you can get under the *O*(*N* log *N*) time complexity boundary (due to sorting); either by (implicitly) limiting *N* (so you can use radix sort with linear time complexity), or by leveraging data order (avoiding the need to sort altogether).

Finally, note that *time complexity* is not a measure of *computational efficiency*, but of how an algorithm *scales* as the problem set grows.  In particular, radix sort algorithms tend to be "slow" in practice, with several *O*(*N* log *N*) being "faster" up to a very large *N* (last time I checked, on the order of millions to hundreds of millions, depending on exact implementation – computer cache architecture details being a deciding factor!).

Comment: I've already found a solution in $O(n)$ time, your answer doesn't get the point of my question

Comment: @TaChu: No, Lee's algorithm only works on simple polygons, just like Melkman's.  Lee's algorithm is also listed on the Wikipedia "Convex hull of a simple polyhon" page I linked to above.  Furthermore, the "simple polygon" argument in the question only applies if one assumes the points are given *in order*, and are not just an unordered set of points on the boundary of the polygon.  But thanks for the downvote anyway.

Comment: I can't and wouldn't downvote your post (I have too few reputation). Moreover, I specified in my question that the order is clockwise

Answer (score 1):

One algorithm that does the above is Lee's algorithm, explained in this paper
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00993195.pdf